# Poorly performing regex

Tags: javascript, regex, performance

I've a really poorly performing piece of regex, currently it makes Firefox, Chrome and IE hang for a period of time.

Here's the reg-ex:

```
 ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+[/]?)+[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

It's kind of a url matcher, but should only match the requested path (not starting with or ending with a slash).

Valid examples:

- Segment
- Segment/Segment
- segment/segment/Segment (etc)

Invalid examples:

- /Segment
- Segment/
- Segment/Segment/

Using the regex above over all three browsers and using two or more slashes causes the browsers to hang.

It's obviously a poorly formed reg-ex, but can anyone help build a better one?

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A better one would be more deterministic, and without capturing groups:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:/[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$
```

This way you don't have overlapping groups, and you're not capturing things unnecessarily.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is that with the optional `/` strings can be parsed in just too many ways, in particular any sequence of N alphamerics can be matched in N-1 ways.  What about:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]+[/])*[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

i.e. 0 or more (1+ alphamerics-then-slash) and then one last helping of (1+ alphamerics).  (Of course as other answers mention you can *also* put a `?:` right after the open paren if you want the group to be non-capturing).

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
^(?:[^/]+/)*[^/]+$
```

Or if `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` is really necessary, try

```
^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+/)*[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

I personally think, first one should be faster though

Comment: That worked, apart from allowing non-alpha-numeric characters. Thanks though.

Comment: Yeah @Kieron, Thats allow any except /, but I think `[^/]+` should be faster than `[a-zA-Z0-9]+`, and also added a version with `[a-zA-Z0-9]+`.